# jQuery Cookie path

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I use the jQuery cookie plugin for storing cookies, with the following code I can save a Cookie for 7 days, but it only saves it for the page its created on. I want the cookie to be available for the whole website.

```
$.cookie('basket',basket,{ expires: 7 });
```

I tried to set a path, but that didn't seem to work

```
$.cookie('basket',basket,{ expires: 7, path:'/' });
```

full code: this works fine, but it only saves the cookie for the current page

```
function add_to_basket(id,title){
if($.cookie('basket')){
    basket=$.cookie('basket');

    var basket_array = basket.split(',');

    var index = jQuery.inArray(id,basket_array);
    if(index > -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        basket+=','+id;
        $.cookie('basket',basket,{ expires: 7 });
    }
}else{

    basket=id;
    console.log(basket);
    $.cookie('basket',basket,{ expires: 7 });

}
```

Comment: What is `basket`? If it's an object you need to run it through `JSON.stringify()` first so you can store a string.

Comment: @waterschaats can you put more script

Comment: Your cookie setting code seems fine. If you check the cookie in Firefox it will tell you information such as the domain, path and expiry date. This may give you a clue what the problem is. Other browsers should also give you the data too.

Comment: reading the cookie seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I just had the same problem. I fixed it by **always** specifying the path when writing the cookie.

```
$.cookie('basket', value, { path: '/' })
```

This is an issue with the jquery cookie plugin. It will default to the path of the current page.

Comment: When I tried this method it actually set the cookie (in your case 'basket') to an object with a path property instead of retrieving the cookie.

Comment: That is for SETTING a cookie to the given path, not retrieval.

Comment: This is WRONG. It creates a cookie with the value of the second parameter.

Comment: I don't think this is true, I always write cookie with the path "/" property, I just noticed suddenly I have 2 cookies with same name - different values - it was created in "/" as I expected and miraculously also in path "/about"... Not always, but sometimes this happens.

Answer (score 16):

In the plugin file change:

> `config.defaults = {};`

to

> `config.defaults = {path:'/'};`

from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/issues/2#issuecomment-790288

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I found that this occurs only when I minify the `jquery.cookie.js` and when I put in

```
config.defaults = {expires: 180, path:'/', domain: '.domain.com' };
```

it sets the cookie path to  '/', whatever internal page is loaded, e.g., `yourdomain.com/en/page1/page`  - cookie path = `'/'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that patching plugin's body is a nice idea. Sadly plugin is not configurable..  I use wrapper function:

```
$.cookie2 = function(key, value, options)
{
    if (typeof value!='undefined')
    { // setting cookie
        var defaults = {expires: 180, path:'/'};
        $.extend(defaults, options || {});
        return $.cookie(key, value, defaults);
    }
    // getting cookie
    return $.cookie(key, value, options);
}
```

Usage:

```
// set with defaults defined in wrapper
$.cookie2('name', 'value');

// rewrite defaults or add something
$.cookie2('name', 'value', {expires: 1, something: 'else'});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$.cookie('basket', value, { path: '/' });
```