# Cookies updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a problem with cookie editing or deleting.

So I am working on custom GDPR consent, where consent state ("pending"/"accepted"), but if the user accepts it anywhere else but the homepage.

it will create a cookie with another path (example.com/about-us), and if I go to any other part of the web, it will only read pending cookie and show it again.

I am using cookie plugin with jQuery.

example:

[image]

Can I somehow force cookie path to be "/"?

Comment: [Did you use the `path` option](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#user-content-path)?

Answer (score 1):

Due to weak reputation i cannot add comment.
I stumbled upon this recently, and i found the answer existing on the site:
[jQuery Cookie path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326620/jquery-cookie-path)

Below code should do the thing:

```
$.cookie('consent_cookie', "your value", { path: '/' });
```

I would also give this cookie a better name.